# Qualifiers controversy gramatical formula is not being satisfied

Tags: grammar, qualifiers

This controversy why is valid?

[image]

The Grammar Qualifier says the formula is qualifier + verb, exist a puzzling controverting case in the bold sentence below:

**we regretted *a bit*** does not comply with the formula because the verb **regretted** is first than the qualifier ***a bit***

Examples complying with the formula:

- I ***quite* like** that = qualifier + verb

Comment: The "rule" being illustrated isn't as hard-and-fast  as you think. Some qualifiers in some contexts can go either before OR after the verb or noun that they modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording of "qualifier + verb" indicates that the following examples are examples of qualifiers being used with verbs, not necessarily in that order.

The book shows examples of the qualifier going both before the verb (*I **quite** like that*), and after a verb (*might be cheating **slightly***). It depends on the qualifier in question, and *a bit* belongs to the latter group of qualifiers that are typically used after the verb.

Comment: So the wording qualifier + verb is not implying an order?